# Is it possible to use update-typedata with a generic type definition in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm implementing Bart de Smet's solution for adding extension methods to Powershell here:

http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2007/09/06/extension-methods-in-windows-powershell.aspx

It works great! Almost! He's filtering out generics, but that was back in the dark ages (2007), and so I'm trying to figure out if it's possible today with Powershell 3.0. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$ls = new-object collections.generic.list[string]

'generic'
update-typedata -force -typename collections.generic.list`1 `
    -membertype scriptmethod -membername test -value {'test!'}

$ls.test() # fail

'string'
update-typedata -force -typename collections.generic.list[string] `
    -membertype scriptmethod -membername test -value {'test!'}

$ls.test() # works!
```

This outputs:

```
generic
Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]] doesn't contain a method 
named 'test'.
At C:\Temp\blah5.ps1:12 char:1
+ $ls.test()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

string
test!
```

Now, Powershell is able to work with generic type definitions. It just doesn't seem to have it integrated with the typedata system...

Or am I doing it wrong? Is there any way you can think of to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Custom type extension depends on `$object.PSTypeNames` - whatever you see there will be used by PowerShell when it decides if given extension applies to a type or not.

In your first example you are "hooking" your method to type that probably won't show up in any object's PSTypeNames:

```
$ls.PSTypeNames
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
System.Object
```

Obviously, linking method that should be used with any generic to System.Object is overkill (to say the least). You can work around it by creating generics with some specialized function, that would wrap New-Object + add something to PSTypeNames:

```
Update-TypeData -Force -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List -Value {
    'Works!'
} -MemberName Test -MemberType ScriptMethod

function New-GenericObject {
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $TypeName
)
    $out = New-Object @PSBoundParameters
    $out.PSTypeNames.Insert(
        0,
        ($out.GetType().FullName -split '`')[0]
    )
    , $out
}

$ls = New-GenericObject -TypeName Collections.Generic.List[string]
$ls.Test()
```

This is more of a sketch than actual implementation... I guess real proxy function would be much better than just a simple wrapper.